# Qual a origem da expressão "fazer uma vaquinha"? Porque "vaquinha"?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem

É usada somente no Brasil?
Fazer uma vaquinha significa juntar recursos financeiros, de fontes diferentes, suficientes para adquirir algo que individualmente não seria possível. Geralmente é feito entre amigos, para um objetivo comum.  Qual a origem da expressão. Álguma explicação para "vaquinha"?

Comment: Sempre pensei que *fazer uma vaquinha* significasse engordar uma vaquinha. Se pensares que a expressão tende a vir num contexto onde o dinheiro é escaço, faz sentido dizer *vaquinha*, vaca magra ou bezerro.

Comment: Dei um upvote de início por ser uma contribuição ao site — mas agora que ela suscitou a resposta do Jacinto, que revela que a explicação dominante na rede (e em livros!) deve estar incorreta, a pergunta se mostra ainda mais valiosa. Valeu!

Comment: A interpretação do @Schilive tem o seu sentido, especialmente tendo em conta que em Portugal também se usa a expressão "tempo das vacas gordas/magras" para referir a períodos de prosperidade ou escassez - em alusão à vida de campo, em que a riqueza/pobreza é definida pela saúde do gado e das colheitas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As expressões ***fazer uma vaquinha*** e ***fazer uma vaca*** existiam já em meados do século XIX no contexto de jogos a dinheiro. Aparentemente era uma vaquinha no sentido atual, mas especificamente para apostar no jogo. O [dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1891](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bs44AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA961&dq=%22Parada%20feita%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX25SOvJb3AhVCzoUKHQjBAhsQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Parada%20feita%22&f=false) diz:

> **Vácca**, ou **Váca** . […]§ (t. de jogo) Parada feita em commum por dois ou mais parceiros, mas jogada só por um

Em castelhano há *hacer* ou *jugar una vaca* ou *vaquita*, aparentemente a mesma coisa, mas explicada mais claramente aqui em 1882:

> ―Jugar una vaquita, quiere decir jugar á medias, esto es, á partir las pérdidas y las ganancias. Deme V. dos duros nada más… yo pondré otros dos… [minha tradução: Jogar uma vaquinha quer dizer jogar a meias, isto é, dividir as perdas e os ganhos. Dê-me você dois *duros* nada mais… eu porei os outros dois…]
> [Lucrecio Méston, *La Política del Hambre*, Madrid, 1882](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kocIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22una%20vaquita%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjey-eG7Jb3AhVCzIUKHW2EDIo4ChDoAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22una%20vaquita%22&f=false)

As primeiras ocorrências em português são menos claras, mas parece ser mais ou menos a mesma coisa. *Fazer uma vaca* temos em 1857 (negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Já tudo está em derredor da mesa de jogo, ou se não está, a *forca arma-se* n’um apice , e logo ― Papá, faz favor de seis vinténs para apontar ; ― Mamã, vamos feitas no jogo ? ― Snr. Fulano, **quer fazer uma vacca comigo ?** [isto é terrível para um homem, porque pode ver-se na] necessidade de ir esvaziar a bolsa, ás vezes em princípios de pthysica, sobre um rei ou um az […]
> **Uma *vacca*** é a palavra mais temerosa que pode sahir da bocca de uma mulher. Uma *vacca* quer dizer―faça favor de me dar dinheiro que nunca mais torna a vêr―porque a mulher se ganha, ganha para si; perde, perde tudo do parceiro.
> [Arnaldo Gama, *O genio do mal* III, Porto, 1857](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1kIuAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA181&dq=%22fazer%20uma%20vacca%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiByfbk0Jb3AhUkx4UKHQp1B1AQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fazer%20uma%20vacca%22&f=false) e também n’[*A Voz do Amazonas*, 1866](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=851035&pesq=%22fazer%20uma%20vaca%22&pasta=ano%20186&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=79)

*Fazer uma vaquinha* temos em 1860. É um poema um bocado críptico, mas depois de referências a “baralho”, “levanta-se jogo sério”, “Vê-se a ganhar e a perder”:

> Lá diz uma: « *Senhor tal*,
> ***Uma vaquinha comigo***
> **Quer fazer?** […]
> […]
> E eis a vaquinha, que póde,
> Por ser do jogo um efeito,
> Muito bem chamar-se bode.
> [Antonio Joaquim de Mesquita e Mello, Poesias I, Porto, 1860](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CvkRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA280&dq=%22uma%20vaquinha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUl-DS3Zb3AhUozYUKHYvFDIo4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22uma%20vaquinha%22&f=false)

(Esta referência a “bode”  estará relacionado com a expressão atual *dar bode*?) A maior parte dos exemplos são de alguém a propor uma vaquinha a outro, como no exemplo seguinte, “Vá lá uma vaquinha de duas *coroas?*” ([Lisboa, 1881](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890820&pesq=%22uma%20vaquinha%22&pasta=ano%20188&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=12460)). Em castelhano há um [*hacer una vaquita*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8Bg0AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22hacer%20una%20vaquita%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPl6vR6pb3AhWJ4IUKHSFqAooQ6AF6BAgBEAI#v=onepage&q=%22hacer%20una%20vaquita%22&f=false) num jogo em 1848 e [*hacer una vaca*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=0PZDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22hacer%20una%20vaca%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjImtmk_Zf3AhWHyoUKHZBUAJcQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22hacer%20una%20vaca%22&f=false) em 1844.

A primeira *vaquinha* que encontrei no Brasil é de 1886:

> Que animação de vaccas gordas. Ao meu companheiro, autoridade já se vê, propozeram **uma vaquinha de nada menos de dez mil reis**.
> [Diario de Noticias, Pará, 6-11-1886](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=763659&pesq=%22uma%20vaquinha%22&pasta=ano%20188&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=5678)

Temos outro em 1887, que parece ter a ver com corridas de cavalos:

> 1º pareo […] o meu amigo The Last diz que pretende fazer **uma vaquinha no Rebicano**.
> [“Pelas corridas”, Gazeta da Tarde, Rio de Janeiro, 27-8-1887](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=226688&pesq=%22fazer%20uma%20vaquinha%22&pasta=ano%20188&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=7602)

Digo que é cavalos, porque [este outro artigo](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=226688&pesq=%22uma%20vaquinha%22&pasta=ano%20188&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=7486) também de 1887 e com os mesmos nomes que eu suponho serem de cavalos, se intitula “Pelas corridas no Derby Club”, e o [Derby Club](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_Club) dedicava-se a “esportes equestres”.

Agora, quando é que o significado de *vaquinha* se alargou a coletas para coisas que não apostas em jogos? Os primeiro exemplos que encontrei são a partir de 1913 em periódicos brasileiros:

> Agora não se diz mais ― Vamos **fazer uma vacca** para comprar isto ou aquilo.
> Diz-se ― Vamos fazer um deputado.
> [*O Pirralho*, São Paulo, 23 de agosto de 1913](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=213101&pesq=%22fazer%20uma%20vaca%22&pasta=ano%20191&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=2491)
>
> Quem lucra com isso são, afinal, os automoveis, que transitam a noite inteira repleto de passageiros.
> Mas nem todos nós somos abastados para sustentar luxos superfluos e nem sempre se pode ***fazer uma vacca***…
> [*A Fita, Santos*, 7 de maio de 1914](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=036180&pesq=%22fazer%20uma%20vaca%22&pasta=ano%20191&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=1506)
>
> Ha os que preferem **fazer uma “vaquinha”**, tomando um auto, com destino á Tijuca, ao Leme ou á Gavea, ao passo que outros mais modestos, servem-se apenas do bond […]
> [*A Rua: Semanário Ilustrado*, Rio de Janeiro, 17 de março de 1918](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=236403&pesq=%22fazer%20uma%20vaquinha%22&pasta=ano%20191&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=6024)

Por que razão se chamou *vaca* e *vaquinha* a isto é que eu não consegui descobrir. Havia no século XV um **jogo da vaca** que se jogava a dinheiro. Vem mencionado nas [Ordenações Afonsinas (V, 40, 11)](http://www.ci.uc.pt/ihti/proj/afonsinas/l5pg151.htm), que proibiam a prática sob pena de prisão e perda da roupa! Não consegui descobrir mais nada sobre este jogo ou se teria alguma coisa que ver com o nosso *fazer uma vaquinha*. Agora uma coisa é clara: as explicações que se encontram na net que radicam a origem da expressão, por uma via ou outra, no jogo do bicho não podem ser verdade, porque o [jogo do bicho](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jogo_do_bicho) foi criado em 1892, depois da expressão ter entrado em uso no Brasil, Portugal e Espanha.

Comment: Além da questão de onde veio "vaca" como aposta compartilhada, resta também a de quem teria primeiro inventado a falsa origem futebolística de "vaquinha" (depois copiada a exaustão por aí). Em tempo: Ótimo recurso esse o do http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx! ++1

Comment: Acho que no Brasil pode ser diferente do Portugal. Se o jogo do bicho foi criado em 1892, poderia ter surgido depois disso.

Comment: Com o tempo, a expressão “fazer uma vaca”, ou “fazer uma vaquinha” passou a ser usada sempre que um grupo de pessoas rachava uma despesa comum. Décadas depois, a palavra “vaca” ou “vaquinha” também fo... 

Leia mais em: https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/qual-e-a-origem-da-expressao-fazer-uma-vaquinha/ José Pereira da Silva, da Universidade Estadual do Rio de Janeiro (UERJ). 

Leia mais em: https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/qual-e-a-origem-da-expressao-fazer-uma-vaquinha/

Comment: @Lambie, há exemplos de "fazer uma vaquinha" na imprensa brasileira de 1887, antes do jogo do bicho. Está na minha resposta. Deve-te ter escapado...

Comment: @stafusa, encontre uma vaquinha de torcedores para reforçar prémios oficiais do clube (apresentada como prática nova), uma vaquinha de conselheiros (?) par apagar salários e bichos (referência ao jogo?) dum tal Marquinhos e coisas desse tipo, mas isto nos anos 70 e 80! Até 1930 encontrei no Brasil umas 30 vacas e vaquinhas no sentido relevante, mas nada que ver com futebol.

Answer (score 0):

https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/curiosidades/fazer-vaquinha.htm

[fazer vaquinhA](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/curiosidades/fazer-vaquinha.htm)

> Quando falamos sobre o futebol contemporâneo, muitos, logo deslocam o
> assunto do jogo em si para abordarem as altas cifras que circundam os
> jogadores e times que compõem esse universo. São vários os jovens que
> hoje praticam o futebol, tendo a expectativa de um dia, usufruírem do
> conforto e de todas as regalias oferecidas às estrelas desse esporte.
> Contudo, quem sabe um pouco mais sobre futebol, se lembra de que as
> coisas não foram sempre assim.
>
> No início, os ganhos financeiros de alguns times e clubes eram tão
> pequenos que, para contornar essa situação, era preciso contar com o
> apoio da torcida. Só para se ter uma ideia, lá pelas primeiras décadas
> do século XX, o Clube de Regatas Vasco da Gama era uma das poucas
> agremiações que conseguiam oferecer um salário para os seus jogadores
> de futebol. **É nesse contexto de precariedade e improviso que temos não
> só um capítulo da história do futebol, mas a origem da expressão
> “fazer uma vaquinha”.**
>
> Mesmo sem tantos recursos, o futebol conseguiu rapidamente aglomerar
> uma legião de fanáticos torcedores que acompanhavam de perto as
> vitórias e tropeços do seu time de coração. Dessa proximidade,
> observava-se que muitos torcedores tomavam conhecimento da situação
> precária vivida pelos jogadores que defendiam as cores do seu time.
> Foi daí que surgiu a ideia da própria torcida realizar uma arrecadação
> de fundos para felicitar os jogadores a cada vitória do time.
>
> **Nessa época**, para quantificar o valor levantado, os envolvidos nessa
> ação nomeavam o prêmio de acordo com os animais que representavam cada
> número do jogo do bicho. Desse modo, ao conseguirem juntar cinco
> mil-réis (moeda da época) a torcida oferecia “um cachorro” ao time, já
> que esse animal simbolizava o número cinco no jogo do bicho. Quando a
> arrecadação era boa, diziam que conseguiram “fazer uma vaca”, ou seja,
> juntar um valor de vinte e cinco mil-réis, que era o prêmio máximo da
> época.
>
> Com o passar do tempo, a expressão “fazer uma vaquinha” começou a ser
> utilizada sempre que um grupo de amigos se unia para organizar uma
> festa ou comprar algo. Se olharmos para o futebol contemporâneo, vemos
> que alguns jogadores de futebol nem se preocupam mais em “fazer
> vaquinhas”, já que “recebem” várias “vaquinhas” para jogarem pelos
> grandes times do Brasil e do mundo.

**INCRÍVEL!**